# this.getHibernateTemplate().delete(bp) does not delete instantly

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a method in which I do the following

```
// First delete the entry by 
this.getHibernateTemplate().delete(test);

// In Next Line try to load the latest values by 
List<test> = this.getHibernateTemplate().find("from test");
```

In this case, the deleted entry also gets loaded in List of test objects. I do not want the deleted entry to get loaded in `List<test> = this.getHibernateTemplate().find("from test");`

Comment: Is there a commit after deletion?

Comment: No . i don't do any commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't execute your delete until you either commit or flush. You can call flush on the session after deleting and before the call to find.

Comment: It's also about different caches. The same query issued with criteria api should *not* find the deleted entity, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Added the following code to make it work.

```
Transaction beginTransaction = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

// First delete the entry by 
this.getHibernateTemplate().delete(test);

beginTransaction.commit();

// In Next Line try to load the latest values by 
List<test> = this.getHibernateTemplate().find("from test");
```

Comment: I did not try that . i tried with commit and it was working fine :) Anyways Thank you for your help .